# How to add Chmod in php file

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

I want to upload a script on my website so users can upload images it is working good on xampp on localserver but when I upload it to my web server and upload an image it gives me notification that folder don't have permission and chmod it to 777 so I want to know how to and where I put chmod in this script. Note I have already created "Uploads" folder on my server just tell me how to chmod. Thanks

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {

$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
$max_filesize = 10485760;
$upload_path = 'uploads/';
$description = $_POST['imgdec'];

$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
  die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');


if(!is_writable($upload_path))
  die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

   if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["userfile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO uploads (name, description) VALUES ($filename, $description)"; 
   mysql_query($query);

echo 'Your file upload was successful!';


} else {
     echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
}
}}

?>
```

Comment: You should be able to use shell_exec to run a CHMOD from php

Answer (score 0):

Shell Exec will let you run chmod from php.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

If you are still having issues run it over the whole uploads directory. chmod 777 is a bad idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);  // octal; correct value of mode
```

Syntax: **bool chmod ( string $filename , int $mode )**

filename:    Path to the file.

mode:    Note that mode is not automatically assumed to be an octal value, so strings (such as "g+w") will not work properly. To ensure the expected operation, you need to prefix mode with a zero (0):

The mode parameter consists of three octal number components specifying access restrictions for the owner, the user group in which the owner is in, and to everybody else in this order. One component can be computed by adding up the needed permissions for that target user base. Number 1 means that you grant execute rights, number 2 means that you make the file writeable, number 4 means that you make the file readable. Add up these numbers to specify needed rights.

**Note:**   The current user is the user under which PHP runs. It is probably not the same user you use for normal shell or FTP access. The mode can be changed only by user who owns the file on most systems.

Ref: https://www.php.net/chmod

linux Command mode: `chmod -R 755 uploads` // assume in your upload folder has different folder